# VB.NET can't run shadow command in command prompt

Tags: vb.net, command-line, command, process.start

I am trying to run the shadow command in cmd.exe from my VB program but for some reason it will not run the command I have tried a few different things all of which have not worked. I was able to save the command to a batch file and then execute it with success but I would prefer to pass the argument/command to command prompt directly and execute this way. Basically, I have a the user run another program I created to extract sessionid and server name (I then just take the server number off the end). They get a 4 digit passcode on their end that is essentially first two is sessionid and last two are server number (all our servers are named ie smdts-(a number) so I just care about what server number they are on) I then take the four digit code and plug it into my shadow admin program. Here is my current code that **doesn't** work:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SessId As String
    Dim PassCode As String
    Dim ServNum As String
    Dim Prc As Process

    PassCode = TextBox2.Text
    SessId = PassCode.Substring(0, 2)
    ServNum = PassCode.Substring(PassCode.Length - 2)
    Dim fileargs As String = " shadow" + " " & SessId + " " + "/server:smdts-" + ServNum

    Dim Pinfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Pinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    Pinfo.Arguments = fileargs
    Pinfo.ErrorDialog = False
    Pinfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Pinfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    Pinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    Pinfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    Pinfo.RedirectStandardError = False

    Prc = New Process
    Prc.StartInfo = Pinfo
    Prc.Start()

End Sub
```

What does work (batch file which I don't want to use):

```
Public Class Form1
Public pathvar As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)

    Dim SessId As String
    Dim PassCode As String
    Dim ServNum As String

    PassCode = TextBox2.Text
    SessId = PassCode.Substring(0, 2)
    ServNum = PassCode.Substring(PassCode.Length - 2)
    Dim fileargs As String = " shadow" + " " & SessId + " " + "/server:smdts-" + ServNum

    Dim Streamwriter As StreamWriter
    Streamwriter = File.CreateText(pathvar + "\ShadowBatch.bat")
    Streamwriter.WriteLine(fileargs)
    Streamwriter.Close()
    Shell(pathvar + "\ShadowBatch.bat")
End Sub
```

Any help on why the first example is not working would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks!

Tom K

Comment: Use Cassia, which can do this in pure C#.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `shadow ...` as the arguments to CMD.
CMD does not support that.

Instead, you need to pass `/c shadow ...`, which will tell CMD to execute that command and exit.

Alternatively you could run `shadow` directly, without going through CMD.